# Is there a way to force text/chapter before the abstract?

Tags: abstract

I am using a document class report and I need the first page after the title page to have some text on it (it is my layperson summary) and after that the abstract and the main part of the file. Is there a way to do it? I am inputting both that piece of text and the abstract from separate .tex files.

Comment: What have you tried?  Just doing what you described worked out for me.

Comment: @Teepeemm I tried \protect before inputs as well as putting abstract in a minipage and none of those worked, not sure if it matters but the layperson summary uses afterpage as I needed different geometry there

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It depends on how many features of the abstract you need to use vs. normal text.  For example, a one column abstract in a two column report can use `\twocolumn[...]`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo my whole paper is in one-column format and I do not use many feature of the abstract. All I do is \begin{abstract} abstract \end{abstract} and I just need to force it to be placed after a short text

Comment: Nnormaly text is output in the location where you put it in your file. Please provide an MWE  that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.

Comment: Three are two different definitions for abstract in report.cls, depending on whther the titlepage option was used.  One tries to start the titlepage while the other uses \small and a quotation environment.